# how to package the .class under the web-inf/classes as a jar and put it to the web-inf/lib dir

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a java web application name `webapp`,when I export it to a war,the source codes will be compiled to the WEB-INF/classes.

Now I want these classed be compressed to a jar,and put into the WEB-INF/lib.

I have tried this:

create a new java project named `webapp_jar`.

Copy all the source codes under the `webapp/src` to the `webapp_jar/src`,configurate the build path to make the project work.

Add the `webapp_jar` reference to `webapp` project.

However ,when I run the `webapp`,it seems that the classes defined at `webapp_jar` can not be found.

Is this possible?

BTW,I use the eclipse ee ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I use the `Web Deployment Assembly settings` in eclipse. I worked.

You can find details [here](http://steveperkins.net/blog/using-web-deployment-assembly-options-to-make-eclipse-play-nice-with-maven/).

Answer (score 0):

have you try ant https://ant.apache.org/ ?
you could make a jar and copy it to folder you want and build the war after.
But , if I anderstand, you would package all the app to a jar ?
I think your webapp can't work without a servlet or two ...

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to do with maven by creating two subject projects, one to build the war, and the other as a jar project and then use the jar project as a dependency on your war project which would put the jar inside the lib directory when packaging the war.